# GIT - getting 'early eof' error on pull

Tags: git, cygwin, eof

I think I'm about fed up with GIT - I keep getting these obscure errors with no indication as to where or why.

This last is on a pull on a cygwin side with GIT version 1.7.2.3 - I get an 'early eof' message and then it won't go any more.

The repository scenario is:

MAC - working repository
  MAC - bare repository serving as a central store.
  WIN - working repository

I'm pushing to the bare repository and pulling from it.

I've tried re-initializing a bare repository and pushing to it, again from the Mac side.  Still get the error on the Win side.

There is no indication what is causing the early eof, but the last thing I added on the Mac side were some .dylibs and links.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: What protocol are you using to pull? Can you post the exact command run and error output? (Unless there is no output between `git pull` and `early EOF`, but somehow I doubt that.) I believe this error happens when git has received a pack, starts unpacking it, and runs into the end of the file before it expects, suggesting that the transfer mechanism did not work properly.

Comment: Well, one way around it is to bypass ssh altogether and just pull it from a share on the mac.  At least I can move forward.

Comment: Oh, hi - I think we crossed messages.  I'm using ssh.  See the above.  I think GIT over ssh is the culprit (on cygwin, anyway...)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using git in cygwin instead of msysgit/git for windows?

Comment: And does ssh otherwise work well from cygwin?

Comment: It seems to - most of what I do in ssh is terminal sessions and the occasional sftp transfer.  The sftp transfers *could* exhibit this behavior, if transporting binary data, I suppose, but it doesn't seem to.  I think it relies on the OS file-system indicators, rather than encountering an eof.  I'm less convinced that GIT does so...

Answer (score 1):

A coworker just hit this errror while attempting to pull to his local windows machine, and it turned out not to be a network issue at all.  `git reset --hard` fixed the issue.

Comment: I think the problem with doing a 'git reset --hard' is you can lose changes.

Comment: This also worked for me (ssh on cygwin, git fetch wasn't working).